# Why is my render result is just rendering a little square?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I have a problem with my rendering results, it is just rendering a little square of all the image, I don´t know why.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I guess *Render Region* is turned on. In this case, hit `F3` and call *Clear Render Region*, you can also find this setting under *Output > Dimensions > Render Region*.

Comment: I tried that but nothing changed

Comment: please share the .blend file here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and edit your question